# Why is my pagination for the results not working?

Tags: php, pagination

I have an app that searches the database for active jobs and it returns them in a list of results. that part work fine, but the pagination is not working. when I click the link to go to the next 10 jobs it just stays in the same page.

here is what the code looks like.

```
$currPage = (($s/$limit) + 1);

// Links to access additional results

if ($s>=1) {
$prevs=($s-$limit);
$upd_msg_prev = '<a href="'.$here.'?state='.$state.$cid_searched.'&amp;s='.$prevs.'">&lt;&lt;&nbsp;Prev 10</a> | ';
if ($s>$numrows-10) {
    $upd_msg_next = 'Next 10&nbsp;&gt;&gt;';
}
} else {
if ($numrows>10) {
    $upd_msg_prev = '&lt;&lt;&nbsp;Prev 10 | ';
}
}

$here = isset($_POST['here']);


// calculate number of pages needing links

$pages=intval($numrows/$limit);

// Check how many $pages are needed by getting total plus one if there's a remainder

if ($numrows%$limit) {
$pages++;
}

// check to see if last page

if (!((($s+$limit)/$limit)==$pages) && $pages!=1) {
$news=($s+$limit);
$upd_msg_next = '<a href="'.$here.'?state='.$state.$cid_searched.'&amp;s='.$news.'">Next 10&nbsp;&gt;&gt;</a>';`
}
```

Comment: There is a bug in your code in the last two lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is $here=isset...

That function will return true or false so it doesn't make sense using it in $upd_msg... further down in your code.

Comment: Will take that out and try it again.

Comment: I get this notice when I take that out.  Notice: Undefined variable: here in /var/www/html/jobs.aacrao.org/search/results.php on line 254

Comment: I should have included my solution to this: $here=0; if(isset($_POST["here"])) $here=$_POST["here"];

Comment: Thanks @Tom will give it a try and will let you know what happens.

Comment: This is what is happening now, I get a Page Not Found. and this is what it says on it. The requested URL /search/0 was not found on this server.

Comment: Or $here=1; Or something else. Only you would know what the base value would be. But shouldn't the url be something like search.php?here=...

Comment: This is what the URL looks like, but it doesnt got any where. hunter/results.php?state=any&s=10 | if I add your solution it looks like this. hunter/0?state=any&s=10

Comment: Then $here should be used after the ? as a parameter, not the page it self?

Comment: This is what I get now with the latest change to the code. Notice: Undefined index: catID in /var/www/html/jobs.aacrao.org/search/results.php on line 145

Comment: Putting this on hold until I figure it out. Thanks for the help in the mean time.